# Как отсортировать значения осей на графике?

Tags: python, массивы, графики

При построении графика столкнулся с проблемой - значения по оси Y расположены в хаотичном порядке, как можно их отсортировать ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import csv

with open('Data.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    result=[line[-2].strip() for line in reader if line]
result=[e for e in result if e.strip()]
result.pop(0)
array_value = np.array(result) 


x = np.arange(4)
y1 = array_value[::3]
y2 = array_value[1::3]
y3 = array_value[2::3]
width = 0.2

plt.bar(x-0.2, y1, width, color='red')
plt.bar(x, y2, width, color='green')
plt.bar(x+0.2, y3, width, color='blue')
plt.xticks(x, ['None', '-O0', '-O1', '-O2'])
plt.xlabel("Key Optimisation")
plt.ylabel("Efficiency")
plt.legend(["int", "double", "float"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: ну данные исходные хоть приведите в воспроизводимом виде.

Comment: Судя по картинке - вы выводите четрые столбца. А судя по коду -  три (plt.bar(x-0.2...., plt.bar(x, y2,..... , plt.bar(x+0.2, y3,...)). Или код не соответствует картинке, или объясните, откуда берутся данные для отображения в столбце, обозначенном вами как 'None' ?